# Unable to call Map on Flux <T> using Reactive Programming in java

Tags: java, reactive, flux

I am new to reactive (reactor.core) , I am trying to convert these 3 steps into reactive  .
1)Filter List 2) Build request from output of Step-1 3)Call service from output of Step 2but I am getting an error while trying to use map on output of filter,
***Cannot infer type argument(s) for  map(Function<? super T,? extends V>)*** . I am not sure how to fix this.

```
    Flux.fromIterable(listForOrder)
            .filter(ct -> !PaymentTypes.CASH.name().equalsIgnoreCase(ct.getPaymentType()))
            .map( list-> this.buildRequest(returnCT, payment, list)) //use output of filter
            .doOnSuccess(proxyRequest ->invokeProxy(payment, returnCT, nonCashCT, proxyRequest, loggerKey))
            ;
```

Original Code

```
    // filter Non-CASH CT and call Proxy for them
    List<ChargeTransaction> nonCashCT = Flux.fromIterable(listForOrder)
            .filter(ct -> !PaymentTypes.CASH.name().equalsIgnoreCase(ct.getPaymentType()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).block();

    // Build request call PG for NON-CASH CT
    PaymentProxyRequest proxyRequest = buildRequest(returnCT, payment, nonCashCT);
    log.info("{} JSON Proxy Request for chargeTransactionId={} is={} ", loggerKey, returnCT.getId(),
            JsonMapper.toJson(proxyRequest));
    invokeProxy(payment, returnCT, nonCashCT, proxyRequest, loggerKey);
```